# Using Google Maps as layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, layers

Can I use Google Maps as a layer in ArcMap?

Is it possible?

Comment: Displaying Google earth/maps imagery in applications such as ArcMap/AutoCAD violates Google and other copyrights (i.e Digital Globe).

Comment: Is there any new companies that supply this service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [ArcBruTile - Tile Services in ArcGIS Desktop](http://arcbrutile.codeplex.com/)

> ArcBruTile display tiles from
>   OpenStreetMap, Bing, **Google**,
>   SpatialCloud and TMS/WMS-C Services in
>   ArcGIS Desktop.

**Update**:  looks like references to Google have been removed from the ArcBruTile site, likely because, as commenters point out, what they're doing violates the Google Maps ToS.

Comment: How does this not violate Google's ToS which require you to only display tiles in the browser?

Comment: Are ArcBruTile services available in ArcGIS Server?

Comment: @Seth:  no, ArcBruTile isn't a service provider, it is a client that consumes various services.

Comment: -1 This is illegal.

Comment: MarkJ not with Google Enterprise - Annually costing $10,000.

Comment: @Mapperz - actually, it's still illegal no matter what Google Premium/Enterprise license you have. Under no circumstances can you make direct tile requests, you always need to go through the Google Maps APIs (javascript or static maps) with your premium key. Arc2Earth Data Services uses the javascript api.

Answer (score 11):

Direct tile access is not allowed by Google (and this is what ArcBruTile is doing). Usually this will get your IP address banned for awhile but they could also come after you for violating their TOS.

fwiw, Arc2Earth will be adding support for this functionality in the next build. Instead of needing a Google Maps Premium license, you can purchase access at the individual user level (much, much cheaper). Yes, you'll have to pay a yearly price for it but it will be the only legal method for accessing Google data from ArcMap

Arc2Earth Data Services is exactly what you need, more info [here](http://www.arc2earth.com/services/data-services/) and [here](http://get.arc2earth.com/help/desktop/dataservices)

**Disclaimer**: I am affiliated with Arc2Earth, as you can see on [my user card](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/253/bflood?tab=profile).

Comment: It [should be noted](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) that Brian is affiliated with Arc2Earth. This is not intended as a reflection on the appropriateness nor relevance of his answer.