# Importing Google Maps into ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google-maps

Is there a way to import google maps into ArcMap as a raster, vector, WMS or other format layer? I need to use/manipulate the data within ArcMap as Googlemaps does not have the necessary tools.

I tried using the googlemaps engine connector but it doesn't seem like it would let you do this. I've even been thinking about capturing several screens and georeferencing them as TIF files but this would prove very tedious. I just need a quick and simple way to upload a googlemap of a certain region into Arcmap.

Comment: Similar discussion: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/using-google-maps-as-layer-in-arcmap?rq=1 - Short answer appears to be no since it violates ToS.

Comment: Correct. You cannot import Google Maps.  Depending on what it is that you're wanting to do, you could either export shapes (in KML format) to Google Earth or use a provided imagery service within ArcMap, either an included basemap or an AGOL imagery layer, if where your looking has additional imagery (Add-->Basemap or Basemap From ArcGIS Online)

Comment: Im looking for a basemap that includes building footprints because I will need to be digitizing certain ones. I have been looking into how to extract building footprints from satellite imagery but I think this is beyond my expertise... I wish there was an easier way?

Comment: The Open Street Map [basemap](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=79fbdd5b4fbc47da842948b255276893) includes building footprints.  You don't even need to digitise from it, you can [download the OSM data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) and extract the digitised buildings themselves.

Comment: Unfortunately OSM does not have all building footprints for the region of interest (downtown san diego) but rather only some key, unresidential buildings... I need every single building...

Comment: Then have you tried adding the [world imagery](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9) basemap?